# PySpark: Pivot column into single row

Tags: python, apache-spark, dataframe, pyspark

I am trying to pivot a simple dataframe in pyspark and I must be missing something. I have a dataframe df in the form of:

```
+----+----+
|Item| Key|
+----+----+
|   1|   A|
+----+----+
|   2|   A|
+----+----+
```

I attempt to pivot it on Item such as

```
df.groupBy("Item").\
        pivot("Item", ["1","2"]).\
        agg(first("Key"))
```

and I receive:

```
+----+----+----+
|Item|   1|   2|
+----+----+----+
|   1|   A|null|
+----+----+----+
|   2|null|   A|
+----+----+----+
```

But what I want is:

```
+----+----+
|   1|   2|
+----+----+
|   A|   A|
+----+----+
```

How do I keep the Item column from remaining in my output pivot table which I assume messes up my result? I am running Spark 2.3.2 and Python 3.7.0

Comment: This is a bit of a trivial example. What would you want to do if there were more rows?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try without define aggregate column

```
>>> df.show()
+----+---+
|Item|Key|
+----+---+
|   1|  A|
|   2|  A|
+----+---+

>>> df.groupBy().pivot("Item", ["1","2"]).agg(first("Key")).show()
+---+---+
|  1|  2|
+---+---+
|  A|  A|
+---+---+
```